# I want to make a responsive banner

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I want to make a responsive banner. Please see the image.

I am using bootstrap. When I see it on mobile screen, the text and bottom images should scale accordingly. Can anyone help me implementing that? All the images, text should be responsive and scale accordingly. Regards.

**EDIT**

This is my banner normally. On large screen.

[image]

When I see it on small screen, the text and images dont scale, instead they overlap.

[image]

This is the code to my slider. Also I want the bottom 3 images to be hoizontal, not verticle.

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li> <img src="img/slides/1.png" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="flex-caption">
  <p>It's color therapy like you've never seen before!
    <br /> Colorpeutic is available on mobile for <span style="color:red">FREE</span>!
    <br />
    <br /> It's no longer a secret - coloring books have transcended age, and have become a worldwide phenomenon. Just relax and paint in a stress-free environment -- let your imagination soar!
    <br />
    <ul style="color:black !important; font-size:12px !important; line-height:16px !important">
      <li>Available Free on all major mobile platforms including iPhone, iPad, Google Play and Amazon!</li>
      <li>Unlimited colors available for FREE!</li>
      <li>Pinch to zoom on all mobile devices!</li>
      <li>Categories include mandalas, floral, animals, abstract, landscapes and much more!</li>
      <li>Simply pick a color and tap area to fill!</li>
      <li>Easy to save your work, share with friends, or share it online!</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
  <a href="#"><img src="img/app_store.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="height:40px; width:150px;" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="img/google_play.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="height:40px; width:150px;" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="img/amazon.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="height:40px; width:150px;" /></a>
</div>
<!-- end slider -->
```

Comment: Are you requesting someone to write or give code? Show us what you've tried and any obstacles so we can help. Requests are not taken

Comment: I am not a designer. I don't even know the A B C of designing.

Comment: I'm asking if you are trying to get someone to hand code to you as your atitude seems like you want want someone else to do your work. Show us things you've tried or look online for resources to start learning. You shouldn't really be here if you don't anything about programming with bootstrap

Comment: Okay let me show you what i have tried so far.

Comment: @AndrewL, I have updated my question.

Comment: Try adding float=left on the style properties?

Comment: This solved the bottom links issue. Now, how can I make the text and images scale accordingly?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head—sorry

Comment: You may want to take a look at media queries
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp You can set sizes in percentages according to the device size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that thing with the help of `display:table` and `display:table-cell`
It's the best way to show your text for me in mobile view also.

[you can have a look at this for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/1mtcs757/30/)
You can see in it that the text doesn't leave the image and image also behave as a `background-size:cover`. it's the only reference for you that I wanna show. If it help's you just tell me, I will be happy to know.